# Select rows having value combination listed in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables:

- Result containing 5 columns: result_id, num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4
- Ref containing 4 columns: num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4

Columns num contain random int in range of 1-9

Aim of exercise is to display all result_id from Result table which have num values combination present in Ref table and to display result_id which have not met combination criteria.

I've been trying left joining ref to result, but unfortunately no success. Could you please share some light how to deal with it?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Based on your description, you simply want all `result_id` (because the combination either is or is not present), so the question is unclear.  Is the combination in the same columns or in any order, for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `result_id` for which combination exists in the `ref` table then use following `JOIN` query:

```
select distinct r.result_id  
  from results r 
  join ref on r.num_1 = ref.num_1 and r.num_2 = ref.num_2
   and r.num_3 = ref.num_3 and r.num_4 = ref.num_4
```

If you want the `result_id` for which combination do not exists in `REF` table then use the `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
select r.result_id  
  from results r 
  left join ref on r.num_1 = ref.num_1 and r.num_2 = ref.num_2
   and r.num_3 = ref.num_3 and r.num_4 = ref.num_4
  where ref.num_1 is null -- or use PK / Not nullable column of REF table here
```

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is usually faster and clearer than `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`

Comment: Cleaner ?? -- Yes. Faster ?? -- it depens. I prefer LEFT JOIN

Comment: See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121061/220697) an answer on DBA by Rob Farley and Paul White. Basically, the optimizer understands `NOT EXISTS` a an anti-join, it doesn't understand the `LEFT JOIN` and cannot transform it properly.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime, I've worked this out the same way using left join in correct order this time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the columns to "line up" and you want to add a flag to the `result_id` in the first table, then use `exists`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table2 t2
                          where t2.n1 = t1.n1 and t2.n2 = t1.n2 and t2.n3 = t1.n3 and t2.n4
                         )
             then 'present' else 'not present'
        end) as flag
from t2;
```